# Como renderizar um array utilizando o React?

Tags: javascript, react

Eu estou desenvolvendo um app simples utilizando o ReactJS e estou tentando utilizar um `[filter()]` para renderizar os resultados de um array utilizando um campo de busca. Mas quando eu utilizo o `[map()]` funciona perfeitamente, porque os resultados do `[filter()]` aparecem no `console.log()` mas não na minha pagina HTML ?

**app.js**

```
import React , { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import List from './components/list';

const App = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [age, setAge] = useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input type="text" className="names" onChange = { e =>  setName( e.target.value ) }  />
        <input type="text" className="ages" onChange = { e =>  setAge( e.target.value ) }  />
      </form>
      {/* My User List */}
      <ul>
        <List data = { { name, age } } />
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**components/list.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const List = ({ data }) => {
    
    // The states
    const [filtro, setFiltro] = useState([]);
    
    // All registers
    let cadastros = [
        { id: 0, name: "David", age: '20' },
        { id: 1, name: "Bob", age: '20' },
        { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: '10' },
        { id: 3, name: "Bob", age: '20' },
        { id: 4, name: "Chris", age: '10' },
    ];

// const result = cadastros.map( user => user.name );
const result = cadastros.filter( user => user.name === data.name );

console.log( result );

return <li key = { result.id }> { result.name } </li>;

}

// Export component
export default List;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ponto ai é que o retorno do seu `filter` também é um `array`, para exibir em tela você precisa percorrer esse `array` e retornar o `JSX`.

```
const results = cadastros.filter( user => user.name === data.name );

return results.map(result => <li key = { result.id }> { result.name } </li>);
```

Comment: Verdade, faz sentido. Obrigado